# How to make solution explorer search only file names

Tags: visual-studio-2017

When I press `Ctrl+;` and type, VS searches both in file names and in C++ symbols (e.g. function names, class names). That would be OK, except that it is much slower than previous VS versions, due to this new feature.

How do I make it search only in file names?

Comment: The box you type in is actually a combobox.  Click the dropdown button and tick the options you want.  I'm fairly sure you want to untick "Search within file contents".

Comment: @HansPassant: That worked, thanks. Although it's still a bit slow.

Comment: @HansPassant, this deserved to be an answer (really useful and non-intuitive trick).

Comment: @HansPassant what about Visual Studio 2019? I can't see any ComboBox there just regular EditBox

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The textbox you type in is actually a combobox. 

Click the dropdown button on the right and unselect "Search within file contents".

[image]

After checking, the Solution Explorer will refresh on it's own.

Comment: what about Visual Studio 2019? I can't see any ComboBox there just regular EditBox

Comment: This screenshot was already made in Visual Studio 2019. I've double checked just now, and the dropdown arrow still exists

Comment: probably it depends on some settings of environment. I've created separate question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74184192/how-to-make-visual-studio-solution-explorer-search-within-file-contents/74184502#74184502  yesterday and you can see screen I made on my environment there. I can't see any dropdown arrow

Comment: That's a strange issue, good thing that your solution doesn't need to check the 'Search within file contents', as that was a different problem.