# How to make Visual Studio solution explorer search within file contents

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm looking for the way to search all files that containing the specified key word in Visual Studio 2019 solution explorer. At least in scope of current git repo, but it would be better to check every repo at same search operation.
I saw [How to make solution explorer search only file names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53139107/how-to-make-solution-explorer-search-only-file-names) but in my Visual Studio 2019 I can't see any combobox there, just regular editbox.

[image]

Could anybody advice?

Comment: Searching all files for a keyword is straightforward - just make sure you are searching in the solution (you can search selection, document, project, or entire solution). This is basically what Visual Studio does - not sure why you are having difficulty.

Comment: @topsail in my environment it checking just via file names, but not the contents of the files

Comment: How are you searching? Are you using `Find (Ctrl - F)` or `Find in Files (Ctrl - Shift - F)`? What exactly are you doing - step by step.

Comment: @topsail I have added the image to my question that showing the way I'm using. But as I noticed the search operation is working just with file names but not with files content

Answer (score 0):

Use the inbuilt Find features (`Ctrl-F` or `Ctrl-Shift-F`) to search for keywords in your code. You are only searching the solution explorer for files by name when you search the way you are showing in your question here.

See here for the MS docs on this feature:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/find-in-files?view=vs-2019